# C++ Boost :Variable sync between 2 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have the following code:

Main thread notifies worker thread to start/stop some job.In the main thread the trigger is some UI button(Qt SDK in this case):

```
    void PlaySlot(bool checked){
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if(checked == true){

            m_isPlayMode = true;
            m_event.notify_one(); //tell thread to  start playing.
         }else{

            m_isPlayMode = false;
        }

    }
```

Now,in the worker thread,once **m_isPlayMode**  becomes true, some loop starts running for a limited period of time and it will exit when the time is finished or **m_isPlayMode** becomes false.

Inside the thread operator:

```
    while(true)
   {

      boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
      m_event.wait(lock); //wait for next event
      if(m_isPlayMode == true){

          while(m_frameIndex< totalFrames && m_isPlayMode){

           m_frameIndex++;
           ///do some work

          }

        m_isPlayMode = false;
        emit playEnded(false);

     }

  }
```

Now,what is happening that after the loop starts playing,when PlaySlot() gets triggered with 'checked' = false it doesn't update m_isPlayMode  and the program becomes unresponsive.I suspect that's condition race issue as I am trying to lock mutex which is already locked in the thread loop.

I solved it by removing  **unique_lock**  from **PlaySlot** method and converting m_isPlayMode  to atomic variable.It works.

But I want to know 2 things:

1. Are there any perils in such a solution.
2. Can it be solved in another way?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `m_isPlayMode` is protected by the same mutex, hence can't be updated when the worker is running. Use two separate mutexes for these, or atomics.

**Edit:** Fast fix would probably to add a second mutex:

```
void PlaySlot(bool checked){
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_isPlayModeMutex); // <--
    // ...
}
```

worker thread:

```
for (;;) {
  boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
  m_event.wait(lock); // wait for next event

  boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> playModeLock(m_isPlayModeLock);
  if(m_isPlayMode == true){
    while(m_frameIndex< totalFrames && m_isPlayMode){
      playModeLock.unlock();
      /// ... (not locked here)
      playModeLock.lock();
    }
    m_isPlayMode = false;
    emit playEnded(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you think that atomics are better in this case?

Comment: @michael-iv If you just need a flag, then likely yes.

Comment: Note that you do not need to lock `m_mutex` in `PlaySlot` if it is atomic.

Comment: The mutex doesn't matter if `m_isPlayMode` is an atomic primitive. If it is not, just use a mutex around the place where you use it.

Comment: Well,in the example above m_isPlayMode  is not atomic.I don't use mutex with the atomic version.

Comment: Based on your example code atomic seems to be cleaner solution :)